# Should I use "definitely" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Which one is correct? Should I say

Definitely, there are multiple points that we need to improve on.

Or

There are definitely multiple points that we need to improve on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Neither is incorrect**. However, one might sound more natural than the other in certain situations.

For example, if I was asked:

> Do you think there are any ways we might be able to improve?

I might answer:

> Definitely, there are multiple points that we need to improve on.

However, if I was writing a briefing instead of answering a question, I might find it awkward to begin with "definitely," so I might say it this way instead:

> There are definitely multiple points that we need to improve on.

One could argue that there is no need for the word *definitely* at all:

> There are multiple points that we need to improve on.

I'm not sure the word *definitely* adds much here.

Answer (score 1):

The first is only correct if someone has already mentioned something similar that you agree with, something like this:

> A: If we keep going on like this it won't be anywhere near good enough.
>
> B: (that is) Definitely (true), there are multiple points that we need to improve on.

In this case, definitely is being used to link to the previous sentence. If the previous sentence is not relevant then use the second one.